# Testing for the existence of a field in a class

Tags: python, class, exists

i have a quick question. I have a 2D array that stores an instance of a class. The elements of the array are assigned a particular class based on a text file that is read earlier in the program. Since i do not know without looking in the file what class is stored at a particular element i could refer to a field that doesn't exist at that index (referring to appearance when an instance of temp is stored in that index). i have come up with a method of testing this, but it is long winded and requires a second matrix. Is there a function to test for the existence of a field in a class?

```
class temp():
   name = "default"

class temp1():
   appearance = "@"
```

Answer (score 38):

`hasattr(x, 'foo')` is a built-in binary function that checks whether object `x` has an attribute `x.foo` (whether it gets it from its class or not), which seems close to what you're asking.  Whether what you're asking is actually what you *should* be asking is a different issue -- as [@Eli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8206/eli-bendersky)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2672810/4298200) suggests, your design seems strange.  However, this does answer your question as asked.

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for:

> **isinstance(object, classinfo)**
>
> Return
> true if the object argument is an
> instance of the classinfo argument, or
> of a (direct or indirect) subclass
> thereof. Also return true if classinfo
> is a type object (new-style class) and
> object is an object of that type or of
> a (direct or indirect) subclass
> thereof. If object is not a class
> instance or an object of the given
> type, the function always returns
> false. If classinfo is neither a class
> object nor a type object, it may be a
> tuple of class or type objects, or may
> recursively contain other such tuples
> (other sequence types are not
> accepted). If classinfo is not a
> class, type, or tuple of classes,
> types, and such tuples, a TypeError
> exception is raised.

Whatever you're trying to do doesn't seem like a good idea. Please describe your original need in more detail, and we'll help you come up with a better design.

Answer (score 1):

You could use exception handling to do this as well.

```
try:
    val = x.name
except AttributeError:
    val = x.appearance
```